# Remove elements from a list that are contained in other list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists

users

```
[[[u'1-tpbvixq4-j1mjkfcl'], [u'1-oufnhv4b-j1tbyxvt']], 2, None]
```

constrained_users

```
[[[u'1-oufnhv4b-j1tbyxvt']], 1, None]
```

I'm trying to remove `constrained_users` from `users`, but I'm not being able to do it.

This is my code, trying to match them so far:

```
if any(users[0][0] in u for u in constrained_users[0]):
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

But I'm always getting false.

How can I remove the `constrained_users` from `users`?

Comment: @Serge the issue is with list indexing on nested lists though. I think that's the barrier to implementation.

Comment: Swap the containment check: `any(u in users[0] for u in constrained_users[0])`

Comment: `[user for user in users[0] if user not in constrained_users[0]]` will gen a list of users not in `constrained_users`.

Comment: Thanks! @ TemporalWolf